# Would this statement be true: two real numbers a and b are equal iff for every ε > 0, |a − b| <= ε.

Tags: real-analysis

Would this statement be true if we swap $<$ from $|a − b| < \epsilon$ to this:

$$a=b \iff (\forall\epsilon>0)|a-b|\leqslant\epsilon$$

I know that the proof stands if $a=b$ since their absolute difference would be $|a-b|=0$, but I am stuck at the part where we give proof by contradiction. Part that confuses me is this:

$$|a-b|<\epsilon\text{ and }|a-b|=\epsilon\text{ cannot both be true}$$

Would in this case both of them be true thus making this statement FALSE?

Comment: Yes, the statement is true. Why would "both of them be true"?

Comment: Lets say $|a-b|=\epsilon$ can you find a smaller number than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Because of this <= sign I thought that this = would be equivalent to |a-b|=e.

Comment: @kingW3 I suppose not. Sorry if I am wrong, I  am a complete beginner at this

Comment: @MatejR $\epsilon/2$ is a such number, between any two numbers not equal there is a number between them. That is a very useful observation

Comment: @kingW3 This helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $|a-b|\leqslant\varepsilon$ means that $|a-b|<\varepsilon$ **or** $|a-b|=\varepsilon$, there is no reason for you to consider the possibility that both assertions $|a-b|<\varepsilon$ and $|a-b|=\varepsilon$ are true.

In order to see why is that$$\bigl((\forall\varepsilon>0):|a-b|\leqslant\varepsilon\bigr)\implies a=b,$$just note that if $a\ne b$ and if $\varepsilon=\frac12|a-b|$, then it is *not* true that $|a-b|\leqslant\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! This helped a lot